# How to prioritize one constraint over another when the font gets larger

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have a UILabel with the following constraints:

```
 - Align Center Y to Superview (priority 750)
 - Top Space to View, greater than equal to 0 (priority 1000)
```

In normal mode, the `UILabel` is `align center to Y` which is ok. But if I go to `Accessibility` setting and set to large fonts (maximum size) I want my label to use the `Top Space` with greater than equal value.

Right now is still using the `Align Center to Y` in both cases. Is there a way when the font is large to use the other constraint with higher priority ?

PS: below this label there are 2 other labels which get shrunk when font is large, because top view label stays in the middle of screen instead of moving up.

Comment: Are you saying that "Top Space to View" is dropping below 0 for large fonts? That shouldn't be possible given just these two constraints. Are you getting errors in the console indication that the "Top Space to View" constraint is being broken? It sounds like what you really mean is that you want two other labels to not shrink, and instead the larger label to move up. If that's the case, increase their resistance to vertical compression.

Comment: @RobNapier Is not moving below 0. I tried to increase the resistance for the top label, but still it doesn't move up. When the font gets large it keeps using the Align Center to Y constraint. So it remains in the middle of the screen and makes the others labels to shrink because of no space at the bottom.

Comment: @RobNapier Or I think you meant to increase resistance for the other two labels ? I did that and now the top two labels are gone, just the bottom one show. Which signals that the other two remained in the middle maybe and got overwritten by the bottom one.

Comment: Ok I managed to make it work. For the Align Center to Y I changed priority from 750 (High) to 250 (Low) . Now it works. I thought it was enough to just have a value lower than the other constraint, I was wrong.

Comment: I update my answer with screenshots and code, it perfectly work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
- Bottom space to view, equal to zero (multiplier 2)
- Top Space to View, greater than equal to 0
```

Screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

Project - https://github.com/leninsmannath/AutoLayoutBottomFromCenter.git

Comment: Then it will move to the top from the beginning. Which is not what I want

Comment: Sorry still doesn't work. I get to much constraints errors.